# image file upload with extjs 4 spring

Tags: java, spring, extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member I am having some problems with the file upload in extjs 4 and JAVA.

I am using extjs4 and the upload form code is

```
{
                                    xtype: 'filefield',
                                    margin: '10 0 0 5',
                                    width: 296,
                                    fieldLabel: 'Image',
                                    emptyText: 'Select Company logo...',
                                    id: 'cmplogo',
                                    itemId: 'cmplogo',
                                    name: 'cmplogo',
                                    labelWidth: 70
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    margin: '10 0 0 90',
                                    width: 89,
                                    text: 'Upload Image',
                                    action: 'btn-upload-img'
                                },
```

the button upload image has **action:'btn-upload-img' with function defined below**

```
fileUpload: function(btn) {
        var win = btn.up('window');
        var form = win.down('form').getForm();
        alert('VALUE IS :'+form.getValues());

        if(form.isValid()){
            form.submit({
                url : 'company/UploadFile.action',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
                success: function(fp, o) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded.');
                }
            });
        }
    },
```

and my java controller has below function code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/UploadFile.action")
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, ? extends Object> uploadFile(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("QUERY TO UPLOAD FILE");
        try {
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                for(ObjectError error: result.getAllErrors()) {
                    System.err.println("Error: "+error.getCode()+" - "+error.getDefaultMessage());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MultipartFile file = uploadItem.getFileData();
                String fileName = null;
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                if(file.getSize() > 0) {
                    inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                    if(file.getSize() > 10000) {
                        System.out.println("FILE SIZE:::"+file.getSize());
                    }
                    System.out.println("SIZE ::"+file.getSize());
                    fileName = "E:\\images\\"+file.getOriginalFilename();
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    System.out.println("FILE NAME AND PATH IS ::"+fileName);
                    System.out.println("FILENNAME ::"+file.getOriginalFilename());

                    int readBytes = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                    while((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) !=-1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return getModelMapError("Error trying to read city");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

don't know what's wrong with my code above. **my firebug console gives me below error**

```
**uncaught exception: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre>{"message":"Error trying to read city","success":false}</pre>**
```

please suggest me some solution I can try to get my error solved soon.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller sending JSON data (application/json) as response which extjs not supports.
Try setting your response content type: "text/html" and it will work fine.
Change @ResponseBody to ResponseEntity

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/UploadFile.action")
public ResponseEntity<String> Map<String, ? extends Object> uploadFile(UploadItem uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    // your controller logic goes here

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I have come across the same problem with a different server (paste server as used by Pyramid) and digz6666's answer (the content type part) is confirmed (and further explained) at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?120201-Submitting-a-form-seems-to-be-mis-interpreting-the-response-type&p=557527&viewfull=1#post557527

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload file besides  extjs 4 using Spring you can use RestTemplate or Apache HttpClient with multipartData. Spring also provide built-in facility to upload file.

useful link -

http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/

Comment: I am able to upload the image, but don't know why my Image xtype not able to show me the image upload. With the firebug I am able to see that the image is upload and read perfectly. But why its not showing is a big problem for me

Comment: Did you able to save file in "E:\\images\\YOUR_FILE_NAME"?

Comment: yes I am able to save my image after upload to E: directory in images folder

Comment: As much as i can understand in your controller class Exception is raised that why "Error trying to read city" message is displayed in firebug console.

This exception resultant to send response as (Success :false).Most probably there is no option for error handling in your client code.

you can find put one more key error:function(), in your client code to get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into similar problem.

I narrowed it down to ExtJS trying to decode the response as JSON. But the response is wrapped with `<pre>` tag. However when I look in firebug I just see plain json string. Since it is a regular `multipart` form post behind the scene browser somehow wraps the response with `<pre>` tag.

Not sure how to modify this browser behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter's supportedMediaTypes property with `"*/*"`, just like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="*/*" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are throwing an exception somewhere in the Java-side, which is returning the String you are seeing in the Firebug error.  I suggest adding a break point in the catch block and investigating what the exception is.  That will give you a better understanding of what is broken and how to fix it.

Comment: don't able to understand what is wrong here I had just tried to implement the http://loianegroner.com/2011/07/extjs-4-file-upload-spring-mvc-3-example/ tutorial. But I am not able to make it working

Comment: @CodeChimp: The fact that his response contains an error is not the problem here, it is the fact that the response is not handled correctly in the JavaScript (by ExtJS).